# Ripple emulator not working on Max OSX

Tags: macos, cordova, ripple

I am facing problem when starting my ripple emulator for my Phonegap project. When I launch Ripple-Emulate command in General development folder (not the platform subfolders), ripple emulator starts, but it shows error message:

```
Error: static() root path required
at Function.static (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ripple-emulator/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/static.js:49:20)
at Object.handle (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ripple-emulator/lib/server/emulate/static.js:6:27)
at next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ripple-emulator/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:199:15)
at handle (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ripple-emulator/lib/server/emulate/hosted.js:156:17)
at Object.handle (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ripple-emulator/lib/server/emulate/hosted.js:183:13)
at next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ripple-emulator/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:199:15)
at Object.handle (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ripple-emulator/lib/server/emulate/cordovaProject.js:54:13)
at next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ripple-emulator/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:199:15)
at next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ripple-emulator/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:174:78)
at pass (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ripple-emulator/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:107:24)
```

And Chrome indicates that it: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) (could not load config.xml file) although i have config.xml file in my www folder.

This problem cannot be solved also when i launch ripple emulate --path platforms/ios/assets/www, then it shows: Cannot GET / error (again complaining about config.xml file).

Anyone know solution for this?

Comment: check whether you have included cordova.js file or not ?

Comment: yes - cordova.js file is included in my index.html file!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like you are creating an app for an IOS device. But Ripple defaults to an Android device, so if you change it to an IOS device and try, it'll sove the error.

Comment: "if you change it to an IOS device and try, it'll sove the error" - How to do it?

Comment: At the Top left of the Ripple there is a dropdown called Devices, which contains lists of mobile devices, in that choose any of an IOS device.

Answer (score 3):

If your using Ripple with Ionic framework, you need to set a path to the apps www folder (or it will give you those error messages).

```
ripple emulate --path /Users/user/Desktop/app/www
```